# How to make a script run at boot time in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: init-script, debian

I am writing a script to do some tasks at boot up time in my Debian Wheezy AWS EC2 AMI. Sources on the internet say that usual way to do this is to use `update-rc.d` to install the symlinks needed to set it up to run at boot time.

However, when I try this, I get the error

```
$ update-rc.d
-bash: update-rc.d: command not found
```

This method has been working for me till Debian Squeeze. Has the standard way to do this changed in Debian 7.0? I am not able to find any documentation that explains how to do it in the official way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use `update-rc.d` as an unprivileged user? Since this tool is located in `/usr/sbin/` you probably don't have it in your `$PATH`. So try running it as root user or call it via `sudo update-rc.d`.

Answer (score 1):

Your script has to contain a LSB (Linux Standards Base) header which indicates its dependencies and capabilities (see https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts for more about LSB headers).

If a LSB header is present, you can use `insserv` to include your script in the boot process (see https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot for more information).

Answer (score 0):

A part from creating a new LSB script and add is as a start up service which is a more standard approach.

You can also add any minor scripting (like - generate a report, cleanup tasks) to `/etc/init.d/rc.local`.

However make sure rc.local is present and enabled to your run level (usually 3 on debian) - `find /etc/rc*.d | grep rc.local`